# Disconnecting disks from Airport Extreme

Tags: macos, hard-drive, airport

Since Apple released the new Airport Utility with the simplified UI, there doesn't seem to be an option to "Disconnect All Users" to kick all users off a hard drive to safely remove it when connected to an Airport Extreme. See the screenshot for this button in the previous version of Airport Utility.

[image: Screenshot depicting this in the previous version]

How should I do this in the new version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consensus is that Apple simply forgot it - or didn't make the UI clear!

Deselecting "Enable file sharing" looks to have replaced it. At the very least that will disconnect users before you pull the plug.

[image]

Comment: Only thing is that it reboots the whole Airport, disabling everything for a couple minutes, whereas the Disconnect All Users button didn't reboot the Airport.

Comment: I agree it's not an improvement...

Comment: I only ever had one disk connected at a time, but did the previous version just disconnect all users from the disk that was selected in the list?
It'll work for now though. Not that there's much of a choice :-)